# Redirecting a download file to the new named file via htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Over time, filenames of our software have changed for various reasons, so an old download file pointed to by shareware sites no longer exists.

I want to redirect so that if somebody clicks a link to the old file they can download the new (different named) version.

So I tried adding a .htaccess file into public_html that contains the following (and nothing else):

```
Redirect 301 mydomain.com/oldinstaller.exe mydomain.com/newinstaller.exe
```

But that didnt work, I get 500 errors issued by the server. All files are in public_html and so is the .htaccess file. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE

I tried the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldinstaller.msi /newinstaller.exe [R=301,L]
```

and the browser is given this URL:

```
https://example.com/home/admin/web/example.com/public_html/newinstaller.exe
```

And if I try:

```
RewriteRule ^oldinstaller.msi$ example.com/newinstaller.exe [R=301,L]
```

I get:

```
https://example.com/example.com/newinstaller.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

This should make a trick:

Filename: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^oldinstaller.exe$ mydomain.com/newinstaller.exe [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but no joy, see updated question

Answer (score 0):

Try mod_rewrite redirecting using

```
RewriteRule ^oldinstaller.exe /newinstaller.exe [R=301,L]
```

or redirect by adding HTTP headers in your php page

Comment: Thanks for your help but no joy, see updated question

Comment: How the current link is and how it should be?

Comment: The current link is https://example.com/oldinstaller.exe, and it should become https://example.com/newinstaller.exe. Sorry the https:// at the beginning does not show up in these comments